# GCD Summation function

Tags: summation, gcd-and-lcm

I know that GCD summation function ($\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} \gcd(i, n)$ is multiplicative. Thus it can be calculated in $O(\log n)$ complexity using factorization.

But I want to want to compute the same function for but any given range, like for range $[x, y]$, $\sum_{i=x}^{i=y} \gcd(i, n)$. Can it be done in complexity less than $O(n \log n)$ where $\log n$ comes from the time to calculate gcd function?

Comment: If you write "n log n" in MathJax, you will see $n log n$, but if you write "n\log n" you will see $n\log n$, with proper spacing before and after $\text{“}{\log}\text{''}$ and with $\text{“}{\log}\text{''}$ not italicized.  The spacing is context-dependent: notice that in $n\log(n)$ there is less space to the right of $\text{“}{\log}\text{''}$ than there is in $n\log n$. MathJax evolved from software created by Donald Knuth, not by the seeming cave men who created the "equation editor" in MS Word and the like. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.